# Can an APP setup a wifi connection?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, bluetooth

I used to eat in a restaurant which provides WIFI for its customers.
The owner asked me and I'm asking you :)

If we develop and provide an APP for the customer would that app to be able to automatically setup an WIFI connection (or change an existent one with new authentication data), so they can access the backend system in the local network as soon as they enter in the place (detected using BLE/ibeacon) ?